# Hardcode slope and intercept from lm into ggplot 's geom_abline

Tags: r

I have the R code for the slope and intercept of a regression line. It looks like this:

```
A <- lm(formula=A~B,data=Averages)
```

I get this:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)    B
     4.4108    0.4896
```

I want to code that slope and intercept into my code for a ggplot which looks like:

```
ggplot(Averages, aes(x=B,y=A,color=factor(C))) + 
    geom_point(aes(color= factor(C)),size=3) + 
    geom_smooth(method='lm', se=FALSE) + 
    geom_abline(intercept=4.4110, slope=0.4356,size=1)
```

Right now the intercept and slope in the geom_abline portion of the graph I manually enter based on the results of the `lm` code from above. How do I code these into the graph code instead using R?

Comment: you can get these values from `coef(A)`

Comment: Why do you need `abline` in addition to `geom_smooth`?

Comment: the `geom_smooth` works group-by-group.  The OP could also use `+ geom_smooth(method='lm', aes(group=1), se=FALSE)` to get a regression line for the overall data set.

Comment: Geom_smooth is giving me multiple different regression lines for different subsets of the data and abline is giving me one regression line that represents the overall data. I want to have both of these in my graph.

Comment: Repeat your geom_smooth call and add aes(color = NULL) to it.

Answer (score 2):

The lm function stores the attributes of the linear model in a list. To get the coefficients:

```
##Intercept
A$coefficients[1] 
## predictor 1
A$coefficients[2]
```