# How add a PGLS 'abline' in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I fitted a PGLS model, like this

```
fit <- phylolm::phylolm(y ~ x, data = data, phy = phylonegy)
```

and i need to plot the model's line in a ggplot. I tried the geom_smooth function, but did not work. My ggplot structure is very simple:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
geom_point()
```

Using the default R plots the abline function works well with PGLS models:

```
plot(y ~ x, data = data)
abline(fit)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could try `?stat_function`.

Comment: This might help. You'll need to add a `geom_abline` term to your ggplot call that uses the intercept and slope from your fit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059349/hardcode-slope-and-intercept-from-lm-into-ggplot-s-geom-abline

Comment: @JonSpring, this solved! Thanks